# How do I render component based on state

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I've got this filter Icon from MaterialUI and I need it to be filled black (for now it can change position) when a checkmark is checked. When a box is checked setFilters is filled. So if a check is Product Type is ticked, setFilters(prt:[]) wont be empty.

How do I make it so that if setFilters(prt:[]) is not empty, I can render the filter icon with a different position (eventually i'll render a different icon).

I've already tried

```js
 { props.filters > 0 && d.autoFilter ?
    <FiFilter   style={{position:"relative", top:"4px", left: "12px"}} onClick={() => props.toggleVisibleFilter(d.field)}/>:<div/>}
```

```js
// component A

  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({search:'',prt:[],cnt:[],cat:[]})

 
 // Component B
 
 
   const headerFields = [
    {field: 'ID', label: '', width: '5%'},
  {field: 'bnd', label: 'Brand', width: '15%'  } ,
  {field: 'cnt', label: 'Country', autoFilter: true, width: '15%' } ,
  {field: 'prt', label: 'Product type', autoFilter: true, width: '20%' } ,
  {field: 'cat', label: 'Category', autoFilter: true, width: '20%' } ,
  {field: 'url', label: 'URL', width: '25%' } ,
  ]

  
 // JSX
 
 <TableRow>
{headerFields.map((d)=>
  <TableCell 
    classes={{
      root:classes.root
    }}
   style={{ textAlign:"left",fontSize:"18px", position:"sticky", width:d.width, background:"#F28808"}}  align="left">{d.label}
  
  {  d.autoFilter ?
    <FiFilter   style={{position:"relative", top:"4px", left: "4px"}} onClick={() => props.toggleVisibleFilter(d.field)}/>:<div/>}
    {props.visibleFilter===d.field?<MultiSelectFIlter  filterHandler={props.filterHandler}  API_DATA={props.API_DATA} visibleFilter={props.visibleFilter} setVisibleFilter={props.setVisibleFilter} setFilters={props.setFilters} filters={props.filters} />:(null)}
    </TableCell>
)}

          </TableRow>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional approach like this

```
style={`${filters==[]} ? {display:"none"} : {display:"block"} `}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your conditional above, you have an error. For when you check if the array is empty or not you must check the length of it not just `props.filters` but instead `props.filters.length` in order for the conditional to work, otherwise while array is defined and the length is 0 the `props.filters` will always return true;

also since in your case you have defined it like:

```
 const [filters, setFilters] = useState({search:'',prt:[],cnt:[],cat:[]})
```

your conditional should be something like this:

```
{ props.filters.prt.length > 0 ? ...
```